# How to use a "for loop" on a function while one argument referring to a workspace object

Tags: r, for-loop

it was hard to find a meaningful title for my problem. I guess it is better to describe it in more detail.

I want to create a for loop which returns a list with objects created by a function. The for loop gets access to a path in which are a lot of files (E2 in my code). Furthermore the loop should use objects which are already in my workspace (E in my code). For each file in the path and object in my workspace the function should do what it is for. The problem is that it seems that the function did not accept the value (the name) in E as an object for the functions second argument. That is clear so far but how can I implement this in my loop? 
This is my code and I think you will see the problem immediately:

```
for (id in 1:3){
    num = id
    E=as.symbol(paste("Sorb", num, sep = ''))
    E2=paste('mypath/file_', paste(num, 'txt', sep = "."), sep="")
    x=myfunction(arg1 = E2, arg2 = E)
    data=c(data,x)}
```

Hopefully my problem is comprehensible. What I read so far, using lapply could be a solution?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Best,
Tobi

Comment: I forgot to mention, the 1:3 in the loop is because I just wanted to test it with 3 files/objects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **get** function. E.g.:

```
E=get(paste("Sorb", num, sep = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `myfunction()` works for one value of filename, and one symbol. Create vectors for all the files you'd like to access, and a vector of the corresponding symbol names.

```
num <- 1:3
filenames <- sprintf("mypath/file_%d.txt", num)
symnames <- paste0("Sorb", num)
```

Use `Map()` (or `mapply()`) to apply this function to each file name and  symbol (if only one argument were varying, then you'd use `lapply()`).

```
num <- 1:3
Map(function(filename, symname) {
    myfunction(filename, get(symname))
}, filenames, symnames)
```

Comment: get() solved my problem. Your code always produces an error so that the debugger starts. I'm not familar with that so I can't exactly tell you what the problem is but it seems that the function I use is responsible. Anyway, I got what your intention with Map() is about. Thank you anyway!